# Getting Expected top-level statement (e.g. "message").while converting proto to C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am having a simple proto file named Person.proto with the below content. I dont get it what am I missing.

```
syntax = "proto2";

message Person{
optional string name = 1;
}
```

The command I am using is

```
Protoc Person.proto --csharp_out=C:\Users\Owner\.nuget\packages\google.protocolbuffers\2.4.1.555\tools Person.cs
```

**Person.cs**

```
public class Person
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what tooling versions are you using there? If it isn't expecting the "syntax" keyword, that suggests a very old tooling version. Maybe try updating? However, the current Google tools only support "proto3" syntax. In your case, that just means changing "proto2" to "proto3" and removing the "optional". You could also try my online tooling which provides support for both the Google tools (protoc) and the protobuf-net tools (protogen) - see the drop-down at https://protogen.marcgravell.com

Unlike protoc, protogen supports both "proto2" and "proto3" syntax. There are links on the page for how to access the tools locally.